# Generating an atom or rss feed as part of an msbuild process

Tags: msbuild, rss, feed, atom-feed

I'm thinking it would be convenient to alert interested parties to the completion of the build process via an Atom or RSS feed. I'm guessing someone somewhere has taken the time to do this, but...maybe your google-fu is better than mine, but this turns out to be a hard thing to search for.

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty easy to do via an executable task that uses System.Syndication....

If you're using cc.net, another approach is to use cctray.exe